# Change scrolling speed of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, scroll

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="intro-image">
    <div id="intro-text">
        <p class="intro-head">COLIN STEWART</p>
        <p class="intro-body">logos - branding - web</p>
        <a href="#work-anchor" class="smoothScroll"><div id="portfolio-button">PORTFOLIO</div></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#about-anchor" class="smoothScroll"><img src="images/arrow.png" id="arrow" class="animated bounce"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#intro-image {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/desk.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#intro-text {
    width: 1200px;
    max-width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 55%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.intro-head {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.intro-body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.5;
}

#portfolio-button {
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    padding-top: 18px;
    width: 185px;
    height: 38px;
    background-color: #ef3c5f;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#portfolio-button:hover {
    /*box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #c42c50;*/
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
/* Smooth Scroll */

$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});

/* Background Image Scroll Speed */

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $win = $(window);

    $('#intro-image').each(function(){
        var scroll_speed = 2;
        var $this = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var bgScroll = -(($win.scrollTop() - $this.offset().top)/ scroll_speed);
            var bgPosition = 'center '+ bgScroll + 'px';
            $this.css({ backgroundPosition: bgPosition });
        });
    });
});
```

Now I simply want the text (#intro-text div) to scroll slower. How can I achieve this (as simply as possible)?

For the record, I know almost no javascript/jQuery yet, I achieve what I have so far through kind peoples help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't test your code, no time but from what I see right now I would say give `var scroll_speed` a value like `0.2` or something below `1`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if I was unclear, see my reply to Benjamin.

Answer (score 0):

Like expected, changing scroll_speed value works fine.

See above:
https://jsfiddle.net/ojsrfy1r/2/

```
/* Background Image Scroll Speed */

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $win = $(window);

    $('#intro-image').each(function(){
        var scroll_speed = 0.2; // modified value
        var $this = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var bgScroll = -(($win.scrollTop() - $this.offset().top)/ scroll_speed);
            var bgPosition = 'center '+ bgScroll + 'px';
            $this.css({ backgroundPosition: bgPosition });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Benjamin. The background image was fine, that was already scrolling slower (although, funnily enough, I hadn't tried under 1 for the value and now it works better). It is the text (#intro-text) that I now want to change scroll speed for. I have tried just duplicating the same code and changing #intro-image for #intro-text, but it doesn't seem to work the same.

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You can use a Lib like skrollr for jquery (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) or SparkScroll directive/component for Angular/React (https://github.com/gilbox/spark-scroll). I worked on them and they're all good. 

But, tonight i can send you an example of code to do it manually, without a lib. 
To do it yourself manualy, you can begin by modifying your #intro-image function to change 'top' style parameter of your #intro-text division, based on scroll position. You also have to set an absolute position on #intro-text width css.